# Is it possible to create a default workspace in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, workspace, default

I have been using QGIS for quite some time. It always happens that I change the position of toolbars and panels to make the workflow more efficient. But then when I close QGIS and I have to start a new project, the position of toolbars and panels remain the same. I have to put them back individually to their position.

My question is, is it possible to create a default workspace? I mean, if I want to put back at once all the tools and panels in their position, I just have to click one or two buttons. Like in photoshop, they have several workspaces.

Comment: QGIS should remember the layout of the toolbars and panels on each close.  What platform are you on?

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I am using QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour. Yes, that is what happens, it remembers the layout of the toolbars and panels on each close. For me, it is less a problem. Actually, I am learning QGIS now with the NGO workers and some people in the community. But they find it hard to look for panels and toolbars when their positions change. So I am thinking maybe there is a way to put back at once all the panels and toolbars into default workspace with one or two clicks. Thank you!

Comment: I think what he's asking for is a way to return to the *default* layout. This would be useful in cases of a shared computer where one person has moved things around and then another person comes along and can't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

You could try customizing the layout using the customization options in the settings menu. This allows you to remove superfluous and unused icons and layout the screen a bit. You can save this as a .ini file which can then be loaded through the same menu.

Go to settings-> customization

Untick the menus you don't want to see then click on the save icon.

It's a really good way of setting a standard layout.